# Android ListView inside a ListView ItemClick (click event)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin

So I have a one main `ListView` and when any one item is clicked on that `ListView`, it expands and shows another `Listview` (sub-ListView).  And that seems to work fine.

But once I click on the main ListView item, I can't seem to close it. 
First click, it expands it so I can see the sub-listview but I can't close that sub-listview by clicking on the same item again.  I have to click on another item to close that first one and now the 2nd one is open.

Basically, once I click on an item, one of 5 items I have always stay open.

I tried debugging it but once it's open, it doesn't even register a `ItemClick` event on that item.

For example:

```
this.mylistView.ItemClick += (sender, e) => {
    this.myListViewAdapter.refreshTable(e.position);
}
```

I put a breakpoint inside the ItemClick event and it does't stop if i click on the open item.  It will stop if I click on any other item.  How can I manually register a click on the expanded item?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you dont use **ExpandableListView**? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: one of my colleague started working on this. He started with this. I will change it over to ExpandableListView but for now, I am looking for a temporary solution for this.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You have a classic case of "stolen clicks", from what I can see the inner listview is clickable thus click event will reach it and get handled by it. I'd suggest to add a view (like a button for example) inside each row of the main ListView which will fold that row

Comment: if I understand your suggestion correctly, wouldn't that only work if the user clicked on that button? the item already has a custom style applied (color, size, shadow, etc..) and if i add a button, i would have to make it transparent so it doesn't look bad. and it would only work if the user clicked on that button.